# Constant vector and differential geometry

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, cross-product

I have been asked to solve the following problem for my differential geometry class:

Let *u*(*t*) = ($u_1$(*t*), *$u_2$*(*t*), *$u_3$*(*t*)) and *v*(*t*) = (*$v_1$*(*t*), *$v_2$*(*t*), *$v_3$*(*t*)) be differentiable maps from the
interval (*a*,*b*) into $\mathbb{R}^3$.
If the derivatives *u'(t)* and *v'(t)* satisfy the conditions:
$$u'(t) = au(t) +bv(t) $$
$$ v'(t) = cu(t) - av(t) $$

where a, b, and c are constants, show that *u*(*t*) ∧ *v*(*t*) is a constant vector.

I am having some issues with this problem. I think part of that comes from the fact that I don't really understand what the constant vector. If anybody could answer that and offer some advice on how to begin that would be great. I guess I also don't really understand why we would need to the derivative condition as well.

Comment: You don't understand what a constant vector is?

Comment: Evidently not... geometrically at least.

Comment: You know what a constant function is?

Comment: A horizontal or vertical straight line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You want to show $\frac{d}{dt}[u(t)\wedge v(t)] = 0$. Consider using the product rule $$\frac{d}{dt}[u(t)\wedge v(t)] = u'(t) \wedge v(t) + u(t) \wedge v'(t)$$ and substituting the expressions of $u'$ and $v'$ into the right-hand side the above equation.

Comment: Ahh. Okay, I think I get it. So the reasoning is that if the derivative of the cross product is equal to zero, then the cross product is itself a constant vector, because the derivative of a constant is always equal to zero?

Comment: @agra94 yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Thank you! I feel silly for not getting it.